# Access Host Web list inside SharePoint hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-hosted-app, cross-domain

I have SharePoint hosted app Now I need to get host web list data inside my hosted app. Is it possible to get data from host web? Suggest some help

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It is possible.

The sample code given below will read data from Blog list from host web and display data in your app.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // Set the style of the client web part page to be consistent with the host web.
        (function () {
            'use strict';
            var hostUrl = '';
            if (document.URL.indexOf('?') != -1) {
                var params = document.URL.split('?')[1].split('&');
                for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                    var p = decodeURIComponent(params[i]);
                    if (/^SPHostUrl=/i.test(p)) {
                        hostUrl = p.split('=')[1];
                        document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + hostUrl + '/_layouts/15/defaultcss.ashx" />');
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (hostUrl == '') {
                document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_layouts/15/1033/styles/themable/corev15.css" />');
            }
        })();
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        var hostweburl;
        var appweburl;
        // Load the required SharePoint libraries
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //Get the URI decoded URLs.
            hostweburl =
                decodeURIComponent(
                    getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl")
            );
            appweburl =
                decodeURIComponent(
                    getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl")
            );
            // resources are in URLs in the form:
            // web_url/_layouts/15/resource
            var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";
            // Load the js files and continue to the successHandler
            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", execCrossDomainRequest);
        });
        // Function to prepare and issue the request to get
        //  SharePoint data
        function execCrossDomainRequest() {
            // executor: The RequestExecutor object
            // Initialize the RequestExecutor with the app web URL.
            var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
            // Issue the call against the app web.
            // To get the title using REST we can hit the endpoint:
            //      appweburl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items
            // The response formats the data in the JSON format.
            // The functions successHandler and errorHandler attend the
            //      sucess and error events respectively.
            executor.executeAsync(
                {
                    url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('Posts')/items?@target='" + hostweburl + "/blog'&$top=1",
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                    success: successHandler,
                    error: errorHandler
                }
            );
        }
        // Function to handle the success event.
        // Prints the data to the page.
        function successHandler(data) {
            var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
            var blogsHTML = "";
            var results = jsonObject.d.results;
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                blogsHTML = blogsHTML + "<div><a href=\"" + hostweburl + "/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=" + results[i].ID + "\" target=\"_blank\">" + results[i].Title + "</a></div><br>";
            }
            $('#internal').append(blogsHTML);
        }
        // Function to handle the error event.
        // Prints the error message to the page.
        function errorHandler(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
            document.getElementById("internal").innerText =
                "Could not complete cross-domain call: " + errorMessage;
        }
        // Function to retrieve a query string value.
        // For production purposes you may want to use
        //  a library to handle the query string.
        function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
            var params =
                document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
            var strParams = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
                var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
                if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
                    return singleParam[1];
            }
        }
    </script>
```

You can find detail description about the code [SharePoint Hosted App to access list data in your Host Web](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nickpinheiro/2015/01/30/build-a-sharepoint-hosted-app-to-access-list-data-in-your-host-web-using-the-rest-api-in-10-easy-steps/)

Also there is another good blog on this [Access SharePoint 2013 data from add-ins using the cross-domain library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179927.aspx)

Also [Get Host Web List data in SharePoint-Hosted App](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/get-host-web-list-data-in-sharepointhosted-app)

I have already implemented this code so I am confident about this code.